# QDockWidget doesn't show when code get rewritten with smart-pointers

Tags: qt, smart-pointers

I want to have a `QDockWidget` appear on the screen so I used this code :

```
QDockWidget *dock = new QDockWidget("Title-1", this) //'this' is the main window
dock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
this->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock);
```

And it works as I expected : A `QDockWidget` appear on the screen

But when I try to rewrite the code implementing smart pointer, it wouldn't show up on the screen. Here's the code (I have `<memory>` included) :

```
std::unique_ptr<QDockWidget> dock(new QDockWidget("Project", this));
dock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock.get());
```

Can somebody explain why it wouldn't work ?

Comment: You're probably letting your `std::unique_ptr` `lock` go out of scope causing the managed `QDockWidget` to be deleted.

Comment: Most of the time, you do not need smart pointers with `QWidget`s derivatives. Memory management is mostly done using [object trees](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt uses the concept of [Object Trees & Ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html), especially for GUI classes (derivatives of `QWidget`). If you pass a parent `QWidget` to the [constructor of a `QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget), the child will automatically be destructed on parent destruction. So, you don't need any smart pointer type for these classes.

Using a smart pointer may destruct your `QDockWidget` too early (i.e. when the unique pointer goes out of scope, for example on function return for local variables) and hence the item will be removed from the parent `QWidget`.